# UICollection view in image background as transparent without making the cells in it transparent in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How can I make the background of UICollection view as transparent without making the cells in it transparent in Swift

[Image 1][2]

[Image 2](http://i.hizliresim.com/7BQ2kL.png)

Comment: image link not working

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/mXRqP4.png  https://i.hizliresim.com/7BQ2kL.png

Comment: Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the tour of the site.

Comment: Upload them to imgur. You can do it through your question also, edit it and find the upload image option.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set background color:

```
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Comment: image background to transparent convert how to